# Does the principle of double-effect apply to supererogatory acts?

Tags: ethics, aquinas

Does the principle of double-effect apply to supererogatory acts, or only to acts one is obliged to perform?

Comment: Please explain to me what that means and how it relates to my question. Thanks. 

Comment: Ok. I think that double-effect means that you intend a good result but there are also some unintended bad effects, which you would like to know of in advance. I differ with the idea that one can predict all the effects of an action in advance, so we can only do our best and accept what comes of it. If I misunderstood, I will politely delete my contribution.

Comment: @ScottRowe Yes, that's essentially the principle.

Comment: It seems like a very vast question so I can try to point to some relevant material hopefully: https://philarchive.org/archive/GRIOTC-5 https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781444367072.wbiee907

Comment: @JuliusH. Thanks. Ch. 3 of [_Only Through
Complexity
Morality and the Case
of Supererogation_](https://philarchive.org/archive/GRIOTC-5) has a good discussion of supererogation.